# How to remove or hide element using jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have some code that needs to be hidden. I have tried the code below, but that not fit on my scenario.

```
<div id="zoomer" >
    <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
    <img src="" id="img"/><div style="">Want to hid this div</div>
    <div style=""/>Want to hid this div  too </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the last div but this `div` doesn't have an id or class. I also can't use the `div:first(or :eq(0)').hide()` method as there are lot of divs and it's not possible to tell which `nth-child` this div will be. Is there any method to link with zoomer div and hide it? Thanks

Comment: how do you identify this div otherwise - through id, class, attribute-value or content?

Comment: "I want to hide the _last_ div..." + `div:first` ? O.o

Comment: @Andreas i want to hide last and second last div on basis of parent div.Thanks

Comment: you want to hide all div's with style="" ?

Comment: This info, _"and second last div..."_, should be part of the question and not hidden in a comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Both examples are with background-color: red just for the example.

You can use the `:last-child` pseudo-class:

```css
#zoomer div:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomer" >
  <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
  <img src="" id="img"/><div style="">nice to see it</div>
  <div style="">Want to hid this div</div>
</div>
```

Same with jquery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#zoomer div:last-child').css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zoomer" >
  <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
  <img src="" id="img"/><div style="">nice to see it</div>
  <div style="">Want to hid this div</div>
</div>
```

### update

After the change of the question - this will hide the last 2 divs:

```css
#zoomer div:last-child, #zoomer div:nth-last-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomer" >
  <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
  <img src="" id="img"/><div style="">nice to see it</div>
  <div style="">Want to hid this div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your message.But on my case i want to hide last with second last ? how to hide second last one too.Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "last with second last"? I don't really understand the meaning here...

Comment: On my question i want to show that i want to hide the last div but i thought the code will be generic so will be applied on others div too.I want to change some property like you wrote background for second last item.How would be that possible ? you can check my question now

Comment: So what you are actually trying to do is hide the **last 2 divs**?

Comment: Yes i saw your answer and up-voted your answer but before you other guy answer me so i accepted his answer.

Comment: You should double-check because the other answer is not correct :)

Comment: ok i got your point.I think your code hide last two elements that what i need here but i think @kapil answer is nice where we have no idea of its either last or first but know his position.Generic answer.

Comment: @kapil's answer will give you the exact position (if you know it's position). My answer will give the **last 2**, no matter how many you have. Since this is what you asked - I think it's the correct answer...

Comment: So according to your question (hide **last 2** divs) - the answer his wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

You can user here :last-child, :nth-child pseudo-class

```css
#zoomer div:last-child{display:none}
#zoomer2 div:nth-child(4){display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="zoomer" >
  <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
  <img src="" id="img"/><div style="">nice to see it</div>
  <div style="">Want to hid this div</div>
</div>

<div id="zoomer2" style="margin-top:20px" >
  <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
  <img src="" id="img"/><div style="">nice to see it</div>
  <div style="">Want to hid this div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dekel can you explain why it will not hide 2 div ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `:nth-child()` selector or `:last-child` selector.

**Example:**

```css
#zoomer div:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomer">
  <div class="nice">Which show image</div>
  <img src="" id="img" />
  <div style="">nice to see it</div>
  <div>Want to hid this div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry my code is coming from jquery so can't add static style on that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide the last div but this div have no id or class

you can use the `last-child` pseudo class or [last](https://api.jquery.com/last/) method of jquery

```
$("#zoomer div").last().remove();
```

or `hide`

```
$("#zoomer div").last().hide();
```

To hide the second last div also using [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$("#zoomer div").last().prev().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

with css you can hide the last 2 div

```
#zoomer:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
   display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :last-child pseudo class on #zoomer and set in display: none and it works